# Hide buttons that make sum over number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, show-hide

I have 10 buttons, and would like to make some disappear if they sum over 10. For example, clicking button 5 would make buttons 6-10 disappear, clicking 3 would make 8-10 disappear... and so on.

As a starting point I thought I could use...

```
$(".button")[4].hide();
```

...because $(".button")[4] shows the html of my 4th button and $(".button").hide() alls the buttons when one is clicked.

But this gives a "hide is not a function" error.

index.html

```
<div class="score-inputs">
<form class="buttons">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="1"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="2"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="3"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="4"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="5"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="6"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="7"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="8"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="9"></input>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="10"></input>
</form>
```

```
<script>$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".button")[4].hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Or is there a better approach to getting the result that I want?

Comment: When you index into a jQuery object, you get the actual HTML element. You either have to wrap this with `$` to be able to use jQuery functions or change your selector appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using array syntax you get the dom element not the jquery element

use either

```
$(".button").eq(4).hide();
```

or

```
$(".button")[4].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I see, didn't realise it had different syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using bracket notation on a jQuery object returns the DOM Element within the object at that index. While this could work for you, it would make the logic very long winded.

The simplest way to achieve this is to keep a running total of the clicked values, then disable all the buttons who would take the total over the maximum allowed, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var max = 10;

  $(".button").click(function() { 
    var total = $('.score-inputs').data('total') || 0;
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    
    $('.button').prop('disabled', true).filter(function() {
      return parseInt(this.value, 10) + total <= max;
    }).prop('disabled', false);
    
    $('.score-inputs').data('total', total);
    console.log(this.value, total);
  });
});
```

```css
.button[disabled] {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="score-inputs">
  <form class="buttons">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="1" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="2" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="3" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="4" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="5" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="6" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="7" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="8" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="9" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="10" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped